# Memory limit in Azure Data Lake Analytics

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have implemented a custom extractor for NetCDF files and load the variables into arrays in memory before outputting them. Some arrays can be quite big, so I wonder what the memory limit is in ADLA. Is there some max amount of memory you can allocate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each vertex has 6GB available. Keep in mind that this memory is shared between the OS, the U-SQL runtime, and the user code running on the vertex.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Saveen's reply: Please note that a row can at most contain 4MB of data, thus your `SqlArray` will be limited by the maximal row size as well once you return it from your extractor.